# how can I check a particular gcc feature in configure.ac

Tags: c++, c, gcc, autoconf

For example, gcc 4.7 has a new feature -Wnarrowing. In configure.ac, how can I test where a feature is supported by the current gcc or not?
There's a [file](http://git.savannah.gnu.org/cgit/gnulib.git/tree/m4/manywarnings.m4) in gnulibc, but doesn't make much sense to me.

Comment: Perhaps the question should be generalized.  You cannot assume the compiler is gcc, so you should ask how to check if the compiler supports a particular feature rather than if gcc supports a particular feature.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See http://code.google.com/p/opendoom/source/browse/trunk/VisualC8/autotools/ac_c_compile_flags.m4 for an example test of this sort - this tries to compile a trivial program with the given compiler flag, and adds it to CFLAGS if it works.

Comment: It's the first argument to the AC_C_COMPILE_FLAGS macro (substituted when the macro is expanded).

Comment: This approach is exactly what I warned about: if a `-Wnarrowing` option is accepted by a compiler with the message "ignoring unknown option -Wnarrowing" (and yes, such compilers exist), `-Wnarrowing` shouldn't be added. Your approach does cause it to be added.

Comment: is it means I can call this macro like AC_C_COMPILE_FLAGS([flag1 flag2 flag3])?

Comment: That depends what he wants to do in the case that it does not work. If he is merely trying to avoid having the compiler abort due to an unrecognised option, then this works as-is. If he wants to detect and handle the case that the option is unsupported, then your approach is good and this macro may help him get started.

Comment: Yes, you can call it with a list of flags (see the configure.in for the project that I linked).

Answer (score 2):

Both gcc and clang support `-W[no-]narrowing` and `-W[no-]error=narrowing` options.

With `-std=c++11`, gcc emits a *warning* by default, and clang emits an *error* by default. Even though you only mention gcc, I think you could extend the functionality check to compilers like clang that attempt to provide the same options and extensions. That might include Intel's icc too.

Let's assume you've selected the C++ compiler with `AC_PROG_CXX`, and have ensured that [it's using the C++11 standard](http://www.gnu.org/software/autoconf-archive/ax_cxx_compile_stdcxx_11.html#ax_cxx_compile_stdcxx_11).

```
ac_save_CXXFLAGS="$CXXFLAGS"
CXXFLAGS="$CXXFLAGS -Werror -Wno-error=narrowing"
AC_LANG_PUSH([C++])

AC_COMPILE_IFELSE([AC_LANG_PROGRAM([],
  [[int i {1.0}; (void) i;]])],
  [ac_cxx_warn_narrowing=1], [ac_cxx_warn_narrowing=0])

AS_IF([test $ac_cxx_warn_narrowing -ne 0],
  [AC_MSG_RESULT(['$CXX' supports -Wnarrowing])])

AC_LANG_POP([C++])
CXXFLAGS="$ac_save_CXXFLAGS"
```

Compilation will only succeed if: 1) the compiler supports `-Wnarrowing` related options, which implies it supports `-Werror`, and: 2) recognizes C++11 initialization syntax.

Normally, `configure.ac` scripts and flags passed to configure should avoid `-Werror`, as it breaks too many internal tests. In this context, we ensure there are no other warnings besides the narrowing, which is why `(void) i;` is needed to prevent a warning about unused variables.

Comment: `-Werror` is wrong in this configure test exactly for the reason you say it is wrong in general in configure tests: there are legitimate reasons why that test program may produce a warning (including something as simple as the user adding extra warning options in CXXFLAGS) that you haven't accounted for and cannot account for. I do seem to recall that some compilers issue a warning for the useless statement `(void) i;`, a user's warning options may warn about a C++98-compatibility issue in the initialisation, a user's warning options may warn about the particular form of `main` declaration.

Comment: @hvd - I would be curious to know of any extra flag options added to gcc (or clang) that would give an incorrect result in this test program. Should a configure script have to handle pathological compiler flag combinations in any case? Some flags won't make it past the `AC_PROG_CC` and early tests.

Comment: Not in general, but I do think warning flags should always be safe to add, at the very least because new warnings are added all the time to newer versions of compilers, so checks already need to anticipate all possible warnings. In general (not for your specific example, since you happen to have picked a C++ check), as a pathological example, there are warnings for unprototyped functions, and there are warnings for prototyped functions, so regardless of how `AC_LANG_PROGRAM` defines `main`, there's at least one option to cause a warning. I'll let you know if I find one more specific to this.

Comment: Having tested, the hypothetical warning I was suggesting really does exist in clang: `clang++ -std=c++11 -Wc++98-compat` correctly warns about `int i {1.0};` with "warning: generalized initializer lists are incompatible with C++98".

Comment: @hvd - hmm. That's also enabled with the `-Weverything` flag, which ignores the std and turns on c++98-compat warnings.

Answer (score 1):

The logic behind this should probably be:

Create a correct file that should get a warning with `-Wnarrowing`. Verify that it gets compiled correctly. This is a sanity check.

Then compile that same file with `-Wnarrowing`, and verify that it still gets compiled correctly. This makes sure you detect compilers that don't support `-Wnarrowing` as an option, and don't attempt to pass bogus options to them.

Finally, compile that same file with `-Werror=narrowing`, and verify that it now does not get compiled correctly. If it now fails, you can be fairly certain that the compiler does indeed support `-Wnarrowing`. This last check is useful to detect compilers that do accept `-Wnarrowing`/`-Werror=narrowing`, but spit out a warning "ignoring unknown option -Wnarrowing". In that case, you shouldn't be passing `-Wnarrowing`.

Optionally, you may also want to compile a file that *shouldn't* get a warning with `-Wnarrowing` with `-Werror=narrowing`, in case you find a compiler where `-Wnarrowing` is useless and `-Werror=narrowing` is a hard error. I cannot think of a compiler where this would be required, though.

Translating this to a configure check should be trivial.

Comment: This is brittle, requires 3 compilations, and I can't tell the difference between step 1 and 2.

Comment: @BrettHale There's nothing wrong with multiple compilations during configure checks. They're extremely short programs that are supposed to compile extremely fast. As for the difference between step 1 and step 2, suppose the compiler issues an error when `-Wnarrowing` is passed, but also issues an error when `-Wnarrowing` is not passed. In that case, the error says nothing at all about whether `-Wnarrowing` is supported. This may happen if the test program unintentionally depends on implementation-specific features, and adjusting the test to account for that is just defensive coding.

Comment: This fails for clang - as `-Wnarrowing` is default, and an error.

Comment: @BrettHale In clang's case, based on your comment, `-Wnarrowing` would have absolutely no effect, so based on my approach, would not be added to the CXXFLAGS, and that would be fine, because it wouldn't make any difference to add it. But clang doesn't actually enable `-Wnarrowing` by default, it only enables in C++11 mode. And yes, `-Wnarrowing` does make sense in C++98 mode: it would warn about `int a[] = { 1.0 };`. So with a suitable program, my approach would in that case correctly lead to `-Wnarrowing` being added to CXXFLAGS.

Comment: I'm having trouble following your method here - as clang does support the `-Wnarrowing` feature - e.g., it can be turned off with `-Wno-narrowing` in C++11. Could you supply the `configure.ac` test?

Comment: @BrettHale The question is about adding `-Wnarrowing`, not about adding `-Wno-narrowing`. If the idea is to detect `-Wnarrowing` in order to pass `-Wno-narrowing` to the compiler, then I agree that my approach won't work. I read the question as attempting to detect `-Wnarrowing` in order to pass `-Wnarrowing`, and for that, it doesn't matter for `clang++ -std=c++11`.

Comment: That's true. It might be a test to ensure warnings rather than a feature test to enable/disable in general.